# JQuery addClass for CSS animation not working

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate an img within a div by adding a class, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Please see my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bv2h7nd/1/).

**CODE:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="searchWrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://images.hayneedle.com/mgen/master:AMD010.jpg?is=70,70,0xffffff">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .searchWrapper div > img {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.animate-opacity {
  transition: opacity 8s;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
function init() {
  $(".searchWrapper div > img").addClass('animate-opacity', function() {
    console.log('Animation complete.');
  });
}
init();
```

> EDIT:

I jave another script which is the page loader and it's running a set interval function, maybe that's the culprit? 
since i'm getting in my console `starting anim` but i'm **NOT** getting any `Animation complete.` from the function's callback.

Unfortuneatly on jsfiddle it's working great, but not on my computer.
[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0bv2h7nd/11/)

Comment: This is going to be impossible to fix if we can't replicate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS isn't specific enough (read more about [CSS specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)).

Change

```
.animate-opacity {
```

To

```
.searchWrapper div > img.animate-opacity {
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0bv2h7nd/2/)

Comment: Also, you didn't load jQuery in your fiddle :)

Comment: Actually, it's not working and i'm guessing it's because another script. Editing question now.

Comment: Question has been edited, on my IDE and with chrome, it's not even going into the function (and logging 'animation complete'), it's not going through the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for `.animate-opacity` isn't specific enough, so you have two options:

1. Give it higher importance:

   `.searchWrapper div > img.animate-opacity {`
2. Add the opacity using jQuery:

   jQuery: `$(".searchWrapper div > img").css('opacity','1').addClass('animate-opacity', function(){...});`

   CSS: `.animate-opacity {transition: opacity 8s; position: relative;}`

   Example - https://jsfiddle.net/0bv2h7nd/6/

**UPDATE**

`addClass()` Doesn't have a callback function, so you'll not be able to use this in you case. You will need to use `animate()` instead:

```
$(".searchWrapper div > img").animate({opacity: 1}, 8000, function() {
  console.log('Animation complete.');
});
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/0bv2h7nd/24/

Comment: Alex, thanks but that's not working either.
I'm not even getting the 'animation complete' from the console statement. It's not going through the function at all.

Comment: Ermmm the fiddle works tho. So you must not be applying it to your code correctly.

Comment: Can you throw a few guesses at me why it's not going through the function at all, yet continuing to others after? thanks

Comment: @erezT - Im pretty sure `addClass()` doesn't have a callback, so you wont be able to run a function like you are. If you want to do that you'll need to use `animate()`.

Comment: excellent @Alex, would you be kind to amend my function, as an answer and 'ill vote it?

Comment: @erezT - Done mate.

Comment: Basic jquery doesn't have addClass callback, but JQuery-UI does have one!